# How can I find out what http code is returned on a website redirect?

Tags: http

There is a website when you visit certain links it redirects you to another site.

Is there any way I can find out what HTTP code is returned before they redirect you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, try curl:

```
$ curl -k https://www.gmail.com/
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
```

Comment: That sort of worked. The link I tested showed just Object Moved, then the link to the new location. I tried the same with wget and it showed 302 Found, then after following the link it showed 302 Moved Temporarily.  Thanks for pointing my in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

`curl`, `wget`, ... and other command line web browsers may not be available in all OS, just use `telnet` instead:

```
$ telnet localhost 81
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /one/two?path=x&y=z HTTP/1.0
<enter>
<enter>
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.0.5
Date: Sat, 15 Oct 2011 02:38:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: http://127.0.0.1:81/one/two/x?y=z
Connection: close
```

You can also pass the `Host` header:

```
telnet www.ganglia.gentoo 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.ganglia.gentoo
<enter>
<enter>
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 15 Oct 2011 02:45:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://nagios.gentoo/
Content-Length: 297
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```